# IE11 google maps bug

Tags: javascript, angularjs, internet-explorer-11, ng-map

Ok so I have this weird bug in IE11. I am using ng-map (google maps for angular js basically) and on this map I have markers. Whenever I click on the marker I scroll to certain part of the page and it all works fine on every browser but of course IE -.-

The thing is that page always jumps back to the start of the map. I noticed that the page focuses on gmnoprint class (footer labels in the google map)

So I tried selecting the parent node and removing the class gmnoprint element and it worked for first click. But on second click everything is again jumping.

Does anyone have idea why IE would focus on some google map element class?